# Xamarin UITest iOS: Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar UITests para aplicaciones iOS con Xamarin. Aclaro que en apps Android me ejecutan perfectamente.

Trabajo con un proyecto Cross-Platform, dando la configuración oportuna en el `AppInitializer.cs`

Al ejecutar los tests, me sale en consola el error:

> SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component.

He revisado durante días las [guías para desarrolladores de Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/) y he realizado todas las configuraciones que he visto y que podían ser la causa, como añadir el paquete NuGet llamado Xamarin Test Cloud Agent además de un fragmento de código en el `AppInitialize.cs` para habilitar Calabash:

```
if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD  
Xamarin.Calabash.Start();  
endif
```

pero el problema persiste.

¿Alguien tuvo el mismo problema?

Comment: Yo estoy teniendo el mismo error. Entiendo que lo has compilado en modo Release no? A parte de eso, no he podido hacer más. En Android, puedo ejecutarlo sin problemas.

Comment: soydachi, ya solucioné el problema. Puedes encontrar la solución en las guías oficiales de Xamarin. En concreto, necesitas encontrar las guías referentes a las "gemas" ruby que debes instalar en el proyecto antes de compilarlo.

Comment: Gracias, también di con ello por ahí. Un saludo!